Why does this take longer in a loop?
I have the following code.  If I run it for a single date it takes about a minute to run, however when I set up the loop to run through just a few days, it runs for ages then fails - 1104 tempDB error.
Can anyone see what I am missing or why the loop doesn't just take a minute for for each iteration?
Azure SQL Server
Declare @pStartDate Varchar(10) = '2017-07-01'
Declare @pEndDate Varchar(10) 

While Convert(Date, @pStartDate) < '2017-07-04'
Begin
    
    set @pEndDate = @pStartDate
    
    Print @pStartDate
    Print @pEndDate

    Begin Transaction Loop1

    Insert Into 
        dbo.QueryOutput
    Select
        *   
    From 
        fnQuery(@pStartDate, @pEndDate) 

    Commit Transaction Loop1

    set @pStartDate = Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(dd, 1, Convert(Date, @pStartDate)))

End;


Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific. Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

fails with what message? times-out? runs out of some space?

Azure SQL Server, error is 1104 tempdb.  However I would have thought if it runs for one day, then it should run the loop for a day at a time.  It must be saving something to tempdb for each iteration?

What's inside fnQuery?

please provide the complete error message

1104 is temp DB out of space. So, the contents of that function are important. With a simple function I can't replicate your error. Also, have you checked user permissions to see if you have adequate temp space?
